# Why is there a difference between the output of a logistic regression and a glmnet with alpha=0 and lambda=0 in R?

Tags: r, machine-learning, prediction, r-caret, glm

I am trying to recreate a forecasting output from a logistic regression using the glm function from the stats package in R.

I want to do it with the glmnet function using the caret wrapper.

To my knowledge, a glmnet model with lambda = 0 and alpha = 0 should be equivalent to do a regression using glm, since the regularization term in the loss function is 0.

However, when I use the two models for out-of-sample forecasting, I seem to get very different predicted probabilities. I could understand, if the two packages made models with minor differences due to e.g. different optimization techniques or standardisation of variables, but instead, they predict vastly different values.

Can someone explain, why this is the case? Is caret doing something behind the curtain, which I have overlooked?

Below I have included a reproducable example.

Thank you in advance!

```
##Housekeeping:
rm(list=ls())
cat("\014")

#Loading library
library(tidyverse) # includes dplyr, ggplot2 and other pkgs
library(caret)
library(doParallel) 

### Create data set
set.seed(42)

# Define the number of observations
num_samples <- 10000

# Define the number of independent variables
num_variables <- 3

# Generate random independent variables
X <- matrix(rnorm(num_samples * num_variables), ncol = num_variables)

# Define the true coefficients for the independent variables
true_coefficients <- c(0.5, -1, 0.8)

# Calculate the linear combination of independent variables and true coefficients
linear_combination <- X %*% true_coefficients

# Apply a sigmoid function to convert the linear combination into a probability
probabilities <- 1 / (1 + exp(-linear_combination))

# Introduce noise to the probabilities with valid range enforcement
noise <- rnorm(num_samples, 0, 0.1)  # Adjust the noise parameters as needed
noisy_probabilities <- pmin(pmax(probabilities + noise, 0), 1)

# Generate the binary dependent variable based on the noisy probabilities
y <- ifelse(noisy_probabilities > 0.5, 1, 0)

# Combine the independent variables and binary dependent variable into a data frame
data <- data.frame(cbind(X, y)) %>%
  mutate(y = as.factor(X4)) %>%
  select(-X4)
data$y <- data$y %>%
  factor(labels = levels(data$y) %>% make.names())

# Split the data into a training set and a test set
train_percentage <- 0.8  # Percentage of data for training
train_indices <- sample(1:num_samples, size = round(train_percentage * num_samples), replace = FALSE)
train_data <- data[train_indices, ]
test_data <- data[-train_indices, ]



### Make models

# Logistic regression with glm
# Model training
logit <- glm(y~., family="binomial", data = train_data)

#Logistic regression with glmnet in caret
registerDoParallel(cores=4)

myTimeControl  <- trainControl(method = "none",
                              allowParallel = TRUE,
                              returnData = TRUE,
                              returnResamp = "all",
                              savePredictions = "all",
                              classProbs = TRUE
                              )

# Model training
glmnet <- train(y~., 
                  data = train_data,
                  method = "glmnet",
                  family = "binomial",
                  trControl = myTimeControl,
                  tuneGrid = data.frame(
                    alpha = 0,
                    lambda = 0
                  )

# Results
tibble(glmnet = predict(glmnet, newdata = test_data, type = "prob")$X1 %>% round(2),
logit = predict(logit, newdata = test_data, type="response") %>% unname() %>% round(2))
```

I tried to recreate the results of the glm function with glmnet in the caret package, but I was not succesfull.

Comment: what does `cat("\014")` do ... ???  (By the way, `rm(list = ls())` [is considered bad practice by some people](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2017/12/workflow-vs-script/) (including me; see especially the last paragraph))

Comment: @BenBolker `cat("\014")` clears your console history.

Comment: I'd say this code is a bit of a mess, and unnecessarily complex for the question at hand. If you want to compare a base `glm` with a `glmnet` model, why are you using `caret`? Why bother with train/test split? Why use 10,000 observations instead of 20? (And why are `y` and `data` defined twice, differently? The code could use some general clean-up.)

Comment: You do not need to tune since you are directly carrying out the logistic at 0,0. Best thing to do is to run the `glmnet(x,y, family = 'binomial', lambda=0)` directly

Comment: Thank you everyone for considering my problem. @Gregor Thomas sorry for the messy code. I have now deleted the extra lines with 'y' and 'data'. I made the data set rather quickly, and just focused on mimicking the problem with my original data.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that a `glmnet` model with `lambda = 0` and `alpha = 0` should be equivalent to do a regression using `glm`. Here is a cleaner example illustrating that:

```
## sample data from ?glmnet
set.seed(42)
x = matrix(rnorm(100 * 20), 100, 20)
g2 = sample(c(0,1), 100, replace = TRUE)

glmfit = glm(y ~ ., family = "binomial", data = cbind.data.frame(y = g2, as.data.frame(x)))

library(glmnet)
fit2 = glmnet(x, g2, family = "binomial", alpha = 0, lambda = 0)
```

Now let's compare results. As you can see, the estimated coefficients are nearly identical:

```
cbind(
  coef(fit2),
  glm_coef = coef(glmfit)
)
# 21 x 2 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
#                       s0     glm_coef
# (Intercept)  0.325672354  0.325687161
# V1          -0.287881229 -0.288031418
# V2           0.414651221  0.414762386
# V3          -0.234202671 -0.234289845
# V4           0.260722365  0.260760690
# V5           0.065580533  0.065543993
# V6           0.070576275  0.070596832
# V7          -0.247781752 -0.247786504
# V8          -0.385057385 -0.385175343
# V9           0.008437837  0.008461277
# V10          0.183649133  0.183693329
# V11         -0.053534081 -0.053513784
# V12          0.057467602  0.057459491
# V13         -0.623232708 -0.623414007
# V14         -0.254157078 -0.254269569
# V15          0.566171102  0.566304897
# V16         -0.004162899 -0.004197876
# V17          0.107288515  0.107351469
# V18         -0.179455701 -0.179456087
# V19         -0.163999123 -0.164038997
# V20          0.080993094  0.080966083
```

Predictions are also nearly identical:

```
newx= matrix(rnorm(10 * 20), 10, 20)
glmnet_pred = predict(fit2, newx = newx, type = "response")
base_pred = predict(glmfit, newdata = as.data.frame(newx), type = "response")

cbind(glmnet_pred, base_pred)
#           s0 base_pred
# 1  0.3551045 0.3550613
# 2  0.7669714 0.7669772
# 3  0.5487094 0.5486583
# 4  0.1207074 0.1206710
# 5  0.3931665 0.3931584
# 6  0.4410175 0.4409472
# 7  0.8522338 0.8522855
# 8  0.5955752 0.5955733
# 9  0.1130833 0.1130494
# 10 0.6650424 0.6650364
```

I'll mention that if I try to run the `glmnet` predictions using `type = "prob"` as you show in your question, I get an error. Perhaps that is your issue.

```
predict(fit2, newx = newx, type = "prob")
# Error in match.arg(type) : 
#   'arg' should be one of “link”, “response”, “coefficients”, 
#   “class”, “nonzero”
```

Comment: FWIW as long as `lambda=0`, `alpha` should be irrelevant ... ??

Comment: Also the coefficients are quite different. Perharps you might consider decreasing threshold?

Comment: @Onyambu Not sure what you mean... I don't see any differences in the coefficients between methods until the 5th decimal place.

Comment: decreasing the threshhold might increase the accuracy. I believe the default is 1e-6. Thats fine though

Comment: Tried with thres =1e-30 and the results were quite similar

Comment: @Gregor Thomas. I have not tried with the original `glmnet`-package. Nice to see, it yields the same result as the `glm`-package. But I still don't understand, why I get a different result with the `caret` package. My specifications in the `train` function should yield the same result as a logistic regression. I think my question is more related to the `caret`-package , specifically. I know, that the `caret`-package is intended for tuning of the hyperparameters, and I am running with pre-specified hyperparameters. However, I should still be able to replicate the results.

Comment: Agreed, but when you have a complex problem you should break it down into small pieces. Now you know `glm` matches `glmnet` and you have validated your theory that they match with `lambda = 0`, so your question can be simplified to why `glmnet` called directly doesn't match `caret::train` with `method = "glmnet"`. We've narrowed down the problem substantially. Now that we know the difference is caused by `caret`, I'd suggest carefully reading the `?train` help page...

Comment: I just did that, and I see that `tuneGrid` is describe as *"a data frame with possible tuning values. The columns are named the same as the tuning parameters in each method preceded by a period (e.g. `.decay`, `.lambda`)"*. Your tune grid has names `alpha` and `lambda`, not `.alpha` and `.lambda`, so maybe that's the issue. If not, I'd very carefully examine the results of the `train` to see if there are clues there.

Comment: But your title question, *"Why is there a difference between the output of a logistic regression and a glmnet with alpha=0 and lambda=0 in R?"* has been solved: there is no difference.